Django gettext internationalization/translation not working for production in cloud run with docker
I'm working on website using Django + gettext + docker and hosting it on cloud run, my dev is windows 11 environment.(I went through a lot until I manage to deploy my build). But something funny happened when I'm trying to setup multilanguage support. My Chinese translation config work on my local build but not on my google cloud run.
I'm using Django==5.0.2 and python-gettext==5.0. I followed some Youtube tutorial and did my localization. Works perfectly on my local but not working in google cloud run. I'm using
  # 5. Localization step to make messages
  - name: gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper
    args:
      - "-i"
      - "$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA"
      - "-s"
      - "${PROJECT_ID}:${_DEPLOY_REGION}:${_DB_INSTANCE}"
      - "-e"
      - "SETTINGS_NAME=${_SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME}"
      - "-e"
      - "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=lt3aelaw.settings.production"
      - "--"
      - "python"
      - "manage.py"
      - "makemessages"
      - "-l"
      - "zh_HAns"
    id: Localization make messages

  # 5.1 Localization step to make messages for de
  - name: gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper
    args:
      - "-i"
      - "$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA"
      - "-s"
      - "${PROJECT_ID}:${_DEPLOY_REGION}:${_DB_INSTANCE}"
      - "-e"
      - "SETTINGS_NAME=${_SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME}"
      - "-e"
      - "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=lt3aelaw.settings.production"
      - "--"
      - "python"
      - "manage.py"
      - "makemessages"
      - "-l"
      - "de"
    id: Localization make messages for de

  # 6. Localization step to compile messages
  - name: gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper
    args:
      - "-i"
      - "$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA"
      - "-s"
      - "${PROJECT_ID}:${_DEPLOY_REGION}:${_DB_INSTANCE}"
      - "-e"
      - "SETTINGS_NAME=${_SECRET_SETTINGS_NAME}"
      - "-e"
      - "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=lt3aelaw.settings.production"
      - "--"
      - "python"
      - "manage.py"
      - "compilemessages"
    id: Localization compile messages

I know the lanuage code for Chinese should be like something below:
Simplified Chinese: http://your-domain.com/zh-Hans/
Traditional Chinese: http://your-domain.com/zh-Hant/
I'm also aware that there's some lazy/fuzzy issue so I use code like this:
from django.utils.translation import activate, gettext as _
def index(request):
    showcaseHeader = _('Please contact us to get a free quote.')
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', {'showcaseHeader':showcaseHeader})

I also know there's some folder path issue about lower case upper case for zh_HAns as mentioned below:
gettext translation not working on production system
Here's the tricky part:
Everything works fine on my local: http://127.0.0.1:8000/zh-hans/ has all the Chinese character's I needed.
However, my google cloud run https://myproject.run.app/zh-hans/
give me the page with only "Home" translated to "首页" (in my django.po file I have "Home" translated to "主页") and everything else is in English.
The funny part is, I put the same django.po and django.mo file under de (German) and everything show up just find.
so I ended up having https://myproject.run.app/de/ to host my Chinese translations.
I can't be the only one having this issue, right?

Are you running makemessages through your CI/CD or automation? Why particularly, shouldn't the .po files be something you commit to your repository? You're supposed to edit those .po files after all...

I removed my makemessages part from my cloudbuild.yaml, my de link still works so you are right, I don't need makemessage step. However, it doesn't seems to solve my problem. Translation for zh-hans still not working.

Just check the .po files you're compiling the translations from, maybe the one you run locally and the one you deploy are different? Maybe you have uncommited changes / unpushed changes / working on different branches?

I checked my github, all the .po files are correct. I don't know how to check what my files are on cloudrun, I check my local build image and files are correct.
